# Mostrar variables con comillas en un input desde JavaScript obtenidos des DB

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

Saludos a toda la comuna stackoverflow.
Tengo un formulario, con los siguientes datos

1. En el input buscar ingreso los datos (TUBO "Y" 4" A 2") las cuales me obtiene desde la base de datos sin problemas, tal como se ve en la imagen
2. Este mismo dato se pasa mediante el code_producto para mostrar en un input dentro de una tabla.
3. Al momento de mostrar me corta la letras con comillas. ejemplo en la imagen ref.3

para mostrar en input lo empleo el siguiente code desde javascrip

```
<td><input name="nombrep[${producto}]" class="form-control" value="${resp.response.nomproducto}"></td>
```

Por ahí se puede hacer con el utf8_encode, pero en este caso como lo implementaría para ese de input que esta dentro de un div
[image: Formulario]

Aclaro si lo muestro en solo `<td>` me muestra todo correcto

```
<td>${resp.response.nomproducto}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las comillas hacen que se cierre el atributo HTML, por ejemplo:

```html
<p>Este campo no se muestra bien:<br>
<input type="text" value="Tubo "Y" de 4" a 2""></p>

<p>Debes codificar caracteres especiales para que se vea bien:<br>
<input type="text" value="Tubo &quot;Y&quot; de 4&quot; a 2&quot;"></p>
```

Lo único que debes hacer es pasar el dato por [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) que, en codeIgniter es [html_escape()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/common_functions.html#html_escape):

```
$dato = html_escape($dato);
```

### Actualización:

Solo agrega la función en Javascript para remplazar caracteres especiales:

```
function html_escape(text) {
  return text
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

Comment: Al agregar html_escape el boton se queda pegado y me sale el siguiente error 
Uncaught ReferenceError: html_escape is not defined

Comment: Listo, respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Gracias hermano +10

Answer (score -1):

Acabo de probar esto y me mantiene las comillas tanto dobles como simples:

```
<input type="text" name="uno" id="uno">
<input type="text" name="dos" id="dos">
<button id="buno">ver tal cual</button>

<script>
    uno = document.getElementById('uno');
    dos = document.getElementById('dos');
    buno = document.getElementById('buno');

    buno.addEventListener('click', function() {
        dos.value = uno.value;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero mi input esta dentro de un div, y estoy usando el framework codeigniter.